# Create a time string from a fraction of a day

Tags: objective-c, time, nsdate

All the `NSDate` stuff is a lot to take in!  I have a `float` that is the decimal fraction of a 24 hour day and I want to convert it to an `NSString` in the format `hh:mm AM/PM.`

I bet it's a one-liner if you know what you're doing... ;)

Comment: Please show us the code you already have.

Comment: I have a bunch of functions that calculate various things about the sun's position in the sky.  Among them are the time of sunrise and sunset.  But rather than set my sunriseLabel.text to "0.3452", I want it in a nice hh:mm format.  I am already using an NSDateFormatter like so to get the month and year and day...  [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"]; NSString *dayString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; int day = [dayString intValue];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
float day_fraction = 0.45; // This is your input fraction-of-day.

int day_seconds = 24 * 3600 * day_fraction;
NSDate *tod = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:day_seconds];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:tod];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
```

Result:

```
date: 10:48AM
```

Comment: Perfect!  Works great and better yet, I understand how to use it myself now.  Thanks!